# Appending data to a file

Tags: java, file-io, append

I am trying to read file and print some text in the beginning of each line of the text file read by the java program. I tried to do it but the string I intend to print is getting appended at the end of the file(in a new line).However, the number of times it is printed is exactly same as the number of lines in the text file. Here is the code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.LineNumberReader;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TimeZone;


public class wordcount {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
        {
            try
            {
             File file =new File("Text file location");

              Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader("Text file location"));

               int lc = 0;
               int wc = 0;
                int l = 0;
                while (input.hasNextLine()) {

                   String line = input.nextLine();


                   lc++;

         String str [] = line.split((" "));
          for ( int i = 0; i <str.length ; i ++)
          {
            if (str [i].length() > 0)
            {
                wc ++;
            }
          }

        }
        System.out.println("Total number of lines :" +lc);
        System.out.println("Total number of words :" +wc);
        input.close();
//      String name = null;
//      Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
//      name = k.next();
//      int wordcnt = wc;
//      int l = 0;
//      for(int j=0 ; j<lc ; j++)
//      {

            while(l!=(wc))
            {
                wc--;
//  continue;
            }
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, true);
            writer.write("Hi" + System.getProperty("line_separator"));
                        writer.flush();
                            writer.close();
//  }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
        System.out.println("Error");
        }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, true);

public FileWriter(String fileName,
          boolean append)
           throws IOException
Constructs a FileWriter object given a file name with a boolean indicating whether or not to append the data written.
Parameters:
fileName - String The system-dependent filename.
append - boolean if true, then data will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning.
```

source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html

If you want to write at the beginning you have to pass false to the constructor, or dont even pass the second parameter. Keep in mind this wont append to the file, it will replace what is in the file. If what you want is to write several lines, with the most recent ones in the top, consider a string builder, and then write everything at once.

You can't append to the beginning of the file.